# How to hack iCal alarm snooze times list, so it`s not full with mostly useless ones (like 1 min, 1 week, etc)

Tags: macos, calendar.app, alarm

I'm really annoyed by the iCal snooze times, I have a daily status phone call with the default alarm (of 15 minutes before event), which I'd want to snooze in a way that it reminds me 2 minutes before the event so that I can set everything up and call in by the time it starts.

At the moment what I have to do is to snooze it twice for 5 mins, then snooze it 3 times for 1 minute which is ridiculous.

I have Googled this and only found years old forums where people couldn't find a solution, but I'm hopeful there's some clever hack to change these.

So ideally I'd want a "2 minutes before event" or if that's not possible, just a 13 minutes one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You an add multiple alarms for each event and edit the time.
 In your case you can have 2 alarms one as now 15 minutes before and the next 2 minutes before

or have I misunderstood

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, while it doesn't answer the question it does solve my problem :) I have to set this up on the web interface of the Google calendar I'm using in iCal though, as doing it in iCal doesn't synch back, argh...

Answer (score 1):

Mark is correct about how to set multiple iCal alarms and how to change the time interval, alarm type, etc… However iCal alarms are not the most intuitive to use as you have noticed. You may find a 3rd party app would be more convenient for your needs. [Apimac Timer](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/19686/apimac-timer) is what I use but there are others too that are more intuitive than iCal and some of them incorporate more functionality as well. [Timer Utility](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/30402/timer-utility), [Alarm Clock](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/20597/alarm-clock), [TinyAlarm](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/19366/tinyalarm), [Pester](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/9589/pester), [Alarm Clock Pro](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/4744/alarm-clock-pro) are some of the timer/alarms available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm using a shared Google calendar and this recurring meeting comes from an invitation, so it would be a bit too much hassle to manually set up alarms in a different app, but appreciate your reply anyway!